# Using jQuery to expand individual <li> elements, that are positioned against the right edge of the page?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm having some problems expanding some list elements with jQuery. The lists are a series of social media icon links that I want to expand on mouseover. The problem is that when expanding the width of the li, the ul also expands, and since the images in the li are floated left they appear away from the right edge of the screen. The only way I've managed to get the text and image to sit nicely together is by floating the image. My a elements have a set width of 30px and the jQuery expands the width to 200px.

This image should explain it better.

[image: visual explanation]

Is there any way I can expand the list elements individually and keep the images on the right edge of the screen?

Here's my code:

HTML

```
     <ul id="social">
      <li> <a href="#"><img src="images/iconFacebook.jpg" />Like me on Facebook</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/iconTwitter.jpg" />Follow me on Twitter</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/iconGoogle.jpg" />Add me to Google+</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/iconBlog.jpg" />Check out my blog</a></li>
     </ul>
```

CSS

```
    ul#social {
      display: block;
      list-style: none;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0px;
      top: 283px;
      z-index: 1600;
    }

    ul#social li {
      margin-top: 10px;
    }

    ul#social li img {
  float: left;
    }

    ul#social li a {
      display: block;
      height: 30px;
      width: 30px;
      line-height: 30px;
      vertical-align: middle;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      background: #f47920;
    }
```

jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('ul#social li a').mouseover(function() {
      $(this).stop().animate({
        width: '200px'
        }, 300);
    });

    $('ul#social li a').mouseout(function() {
      $(this).stop().animate({
        width: '30px'
        }, 300);
    });

    });
```

Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: could you put a right: 0px in ul#social li ?

Comment: @BostonJohn - that doesn't fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does it for you

```
ul#social li {
    clear: both;
    float: right;
}
```

The key is to `clear: both` when floating the elements, which ensures they clear anything which would have been on their row.

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kcGZJ/17/

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work, when you mouse over the icon it still pushes the others to the left, even though the target icon stays to the right the text appears to the left of the icon, which is not what I want to happen.

Comment: Wow, this totally does it. Can't believe I couldn't figure out something this simple >_< can't thank you enough. Cheers matey!

Answer (score 1):

here is a fix - it isn't the prettiest, but it works great - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kcGZJ/11/)

```
ul#social {   
      display: block;
      list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
      right: 0px;
      top: 283px;
      z-index: 1600;
    }

    ul#social li {
     position:relative;;
    right: 0px;

    }

    ul#social li img {
position: relative;
    right:0px;
    }

    ul#social li a {
      height: 30px;
      width: 30px;
      line-height: 30px;
      vertical-align: middle;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      background: #f47920;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    }​
```

with the absolute positioning - it is necessery to put line breaks in the list - works

```
 <ul id="social">
  <li> <a href="#"><img src="images/iconFacebook.jpg" />Like me on Facebook</a></li><br /><br />
  <li><a href="#"><img src="images/iconTwitter.jpg" />Follow me on Twitter</a></li><br /><br />
  <li><a href="#"><img src="images/iconGoogle.jpg" />Add me to Google+</a></li><br /><br />
  <li><a href="#"><img src="images/iconBlog.jpg" />Check out my blog</a></li>
 </ul>​
```

Comment: This is great - many thanks, I'll probably end up using this but I'm going to hold out for a while and see if I can crack it without the line breaks.

Comment: could we achieve a similar result by adding a class to each list item and changing the value of the top attribute in CSS? I'm pretty new to this so I'm not sure if having multiple classes is better than having the line breaks.